# How to determine if content-type HTTP Header is xml extension

Tags: java, http-headers

I am handling a http response and if the response is of type XML, I am parsing the response.

HTTP response can be in any format, so I am relying on content-type response headers.

However the xml mime type can be extended e.g `application/xml`, `application/xhtml+xml`, `application/xslt+xml`, `application/mathml` ...

So is there a better way to determine from content-type whether response is of type xml?

Currently what I am doing is stripping the charset, and then comparing the `content-type` for `application/xml`, `text/xml` or `content type endsWith("+xml")`

Is there a better way to determine this?

PS: I am on jdk1.5